# Black CSS image overlay is white

Tags: html, css, background, overlay

I am trying to create a black overlay over a header image and it seems to turn out white instead even though I'm setting the color property to black.

```
<div id="overlay">
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/WP/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cropped-Skov.jpg')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1>Svampe ting</h1>
                    <hr class="small">
                                            <span class="subheading">Posted by krillebimbim on January 30th, 2015</span>
                    <div id="avatar" class="row text-center"><img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d1f1634ce363d7dd8a0ca1522270c858?s=92&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D92&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-92 photo' height='92' width='92' /> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</div>
```

My CSS for the overlay:

```
#overlay{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:#000000;
opacity:0.6;
}
```

And the header styling:

```
.intro-header {
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML in your question since the PHP has nothing to do with this.

Comment: `color` is meant for text not the background

Comment: I changed it to background-color but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gycdmv0t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image has a white tint to it because it's inheriting an opacity of 60% from its parent div, #overlay, as is everything else on that page. You'll need to take everything out of that div before you can get the effect that it sounds like you want:

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
</div>
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/WP/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cropped-Skov.jpg')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="site-heading">
                     <h1>Svampe ting</h1>

                    <hr class="small"> <span class="subheading">Posted by krillebimbim on January 30th, 2015</span>

                    <div id="avatar" class="row text-center">
                        <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d1f1634ce363d7dd8a0ca1522270c858?s=92&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D92&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-92 photo' height='92' width='92' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:0.6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7zu7m2y/

Comment: I think the problem is as you described. I moved the #overlay div before the rest of the html but now I can't seem to get it to become an overlay. It simply pushes the rest down on the page. Even with 2 different z-indexes..

Comment: I solved it now. My other problem was due to lack of positioning.

Comment: Yup, that position: absolute; keeps it from pushing the rest of the content down and effectively puts it on a "layer" of its own. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `background-color` instead of `color`

```
background-color:#000;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the JSfiddle I created [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmpower/ubv4cctm/1/). Was this what you were trying to accomplish? You needed to change your `color` to `background-color`.

```
#overlay{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: It creates the same overlay as I have at the moment. The overlay has a white tint to it and I'm trying to get a darker one. It's basically just a very dark tint I'm looking for.

Comment: Check the JSfiddle again. I updated it and also the code posted here. I changed the `opacity` to 0.8 to get the overlay to be darker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that you need is CSS filters. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) you have some examples.